# JPype class not found, $1 with no inner class

Tags: java, python, jpype

I have these java files:

```
LDF1File.java
LDFFile.java <-- super class
```

which generate these class files:

```
LDF1File.class -- there is no inner class 
LDF1File$1.class <-- no idea where this comes from
LDFFile.class
```

In my python code, I can import LDF1File$1, but not LDF1File.  I get:

```
>>> JClass('aero.blue.bdms.ldf.stream.LDF1File')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/eric/Software/anaconda3/envs/blue3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/JPype1-0.6.1-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/jpype/_jclass.py", line 55, in JClass
    raise _RUNTIMEEXCEPTION.PYEXC("Class %s not found" % name)
jpype._jexception.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class aero.blue.bdms.ldf.stream.LDF1File not found
```

Here's the full code:

```
from jpype import *
startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea", '-Xms1024m', '-Xmx4096m', '-Djava.class.path=./jars/bdms-chunkjava-lib-1.0.9-SNAPSHOT.jar:./jars/bdms-ldfjava-lib-1.0.9-SNAPSHOT.jar')

LDF1File = JClass('aero.blue.bdms.ldf.stream.LDF1File')

shutdownJVM()
```

So i'm not sure why there is a class file with a dollar sign in it's name, and I'm not sure why JPype can't locate LDF1File.  Just to rule some possible suggestions out, there is no dependency injection, no aspectj stuff, no spring, no guava.  This is just plain java.

Answer (score 0):

I had only included in my classpath the jar of the package i was working with and none of the dependencies.  Having added all dependency jars to the classpath, it was able to load LDF1File.java